# QAugmentedReality on BB10

Tags: qt, nokia, augmented-reality, blackberry-10

I want to create augmented reality application on BB10. But there is no 3rd party library is available for BB10. So i am thinking to implement Augmented Reality using QAugmentedReality of Nokia because blackberry said that Qt application will run on BB10.
Is there any sample AR application in QT so i can run that on BB10 and check if it work or not then i start developing my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [official tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/QAugmentedReality_-_Local_based_augmented_reality_component) for QAugmentedReality there is a link to a sample application towards the end. However it's a .sis file, so intended for Symbian. Not sure if you can simply execute that on a BB10.

In any event you could follow the tutorial and just compile it for BlackBerry

Answer (score 2):

WIkitude Lauche its Augmented Reality SDK for the BB10. So now any one can build their application using Wikitude.
http://www.wikitude.com/