# Augmented Reality integration using wikitudes, HTML 5 for BB10 app?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, augmented-reality, wikitude

Note: Might be a repeated question but I didn't find a robust answer from any forum.

Neither I am a BB6/7/10 native application developer nor I am aware of QML coding as it is far away from my coding standards. Come to the point I am HTML 5 or you can say phone gap developer in simple words and trying to develop **Augmented Reality using wikitude** while making an app compatible to BB10. I am facing issue in integration in BB10. Please find below some resources links which I followed till date:

[documentation->phonegap](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/phonegap)

[creating-augmented-reality-application-for-blackberry10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756784/creating-augmented-reality-application-for-blackberry10)

[wikitude-launches-tripadvisor-augmented-reality-app/](http://www.wikitude.com/wikitude-launches-tripadvisor-augmented-reality-app/)

[Wikitudes threads](http://developer.wikitude.com/developer-forum/-/message_boards/message/318332?_19_redirect=http://developer.wikitude.com/developer-forum/-/message_boards/search?_19_keywords=augmented%2breality%2bbb10&_19_threadId=0&_19_breadcrumbsMessageId=0&_19_searchCategoryId=0&_19_breadcrumbsCategoryId=0&_19_redirect=http%253A%252F%252Fdeveloper.wikitude.com%252Fdeveloper-forum%253Fp_p_id%253D19%2526p_p_lifecycle%253D0%2526p_p_state%253Dnormal%2526p_p_mode%253Dview%2526p_p_col_id%253Dcolumn-1%2526p_p_col_count%253D1&_19_formDate=1382803688062&_19_ocerSearchContainerPrimaryKeys=0%252C1%252C2%252C3%252C4%252C5%252C6%252C7%252C8%252C9%252C10%252C11%252C12%252C13%252C14%252C15%252C16%252C17%252C18%252C19)

[qaugmentedreality-on-bb10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356983/qaugmentedreality-on-bb10)

Further, I tried to develop via native code using wikitudes sample source codes but no strong outputs. For more info refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607930/issue-with-arm-and-x86-in-blackberry10-wikitude-app?noredirect=1#comment29106170_19607930).

I would request you to please reply as per your earliest feasible time if you would have any direct solution or you faced same issue in past and get it resolved successfully.